# Query that looks for contract status in another table and flags accordingly

Tags: sql, ms-access, conditional-statements

I have the following two tables:

```js
              Table A   
Contract Number     Some other field
       1                     a
       2                     b
       3                     c
       4                     d
       …                     …


                       Table B      
Contract Number     Contract Status     Date of Contract Status
        1              Status-1                1/1/2016
        1              Status-2                1/2/2016
        1              Status-3                1/3/2016
        2              Status-1                1/1/2016
        2              Status-3                1/2/2016
        2              Status-4                1/3/2016
        2              Status-5                1/4/2016
        3              Status-1                1/1/2016
        3              Status-2                1/2/2016
        4              Status-3                1/1/2016
        4              Status-4                1/2/2016
        4              Status-5                1/3/2016
        4              Status-6                1/4/2016
        4              Status-7                1/5/2016
        4              Stauts-8                1/6/2016
        …                 …                       …
```

I am trying to write a query that retrieves the "contract number" and "Some other field" from Table A. Additionally, I want to have a third field in the query which should show 1 if "Status-2" was found for a certain contract number in "Contract Status" of Table B and 0 otherwise.

What I managed to do so far:

```
Flag: IIf(Table B.Contract Stauts='Status-2',1,0)
```

I used this code for the field that should show either 1 or 0. However, I was unable to include it in the query. I guess I would need some kind of loop, such that for each record that is retrieved from Table A, the loop searches Table B for "Status-2".

The desired result would look like this:

```js
              Query result  
Contract Number     Some other field      Flag
       1                     a             1
       2                     b             0
       3                     c             1
       4                     d             0
       …                     …             ...
```

Can you guys advise?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you really using both MS Access and Oracle here? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: With that sample data, what's the expected result?

Comment: Hey thanks for the replies! I removed the oracle tag. Thought it was relevant since I am querying an Oracle DB. The tag system recommended  adding the db used. 

The desired result would be:

I don't know how to make it accept my formatting. 'code' doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, what you need is this:

```
SELECT t.Contract_number,
       t.someOther,
       iif(exists(select 1 from tableB p
                        where p.contract_number = t.contract_number and p.contract_status = 'Status-2'),1,0) as flag_col
FROM tableA t
```

for each contract_number, if status-2 exists in the other table, put 1 else 0

Comment: Hey! thanks for the quick and great response!
I am trying to implement this in ms access. Does access support case when exists? I am getting a syntax error for the when within the case.

Comment: @jonas778: That's why you shouldn't use tags that don't apply to your question (Oracle?)

Comment: Sorry, thought this was relevant since I am querying an oracle DB. The error says "Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'case...

Comment: @jonas778 I've  been looking online for ms access syntax, I think it will work now(i thought you were talking about oracle.)

Comment: @sagi thank you great wizzard, if I may call you so!

Answer (score 0):

case when and left join will help you

```
 SELECT t1.Contract_number,
        t1.someOther,
        case when t2.Contract Stauts='Status-2' then 1
        else 0 end as column_name_you_want
 FROM tableA t1
 Left join tableB t2 on t1.Contract_number = t2.Contract_number
```